# Add drop down upon selecting the previous dropdown value

Tags: jquery

I want to add 7 dropdowns, but each dropdown should come after the value of previous dropdown as been selected. How can I do it?

Here is my code.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $('#1').change(function(){

    $(this).parent().append('#2');

});

  $('#2').change(function(){

    $(this).parent().append('#3');

});

  $('#3').change(function(){

    $(this).parent().append('#4');

});
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="2" style="display:none;">
  <option value="saab">saab</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="saab">saab</option>
  <option value="saab">saab</option>
</select>

<select id="3" style="display:none;">
  <option value="mercedes">mercedes</option>
  <option value="mercedes">mercedes</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="mercedes">mercedes</option>
</select>


<select id="4" style="display:none;">
  <option value="audi">audi</option>
  <option value="audi">audi</option>
  <option value="audi">audi</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you try something?

Comment: your ques is not clear, can we see markup of anything that you came up with

Comment: *Have you `tried` something?
Anyway, Do you have the values in the client side or do you have to make a serverside query each time?

Comment: This is what I've tried guys!!! Sorry for not writing the code it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want something like the following.

```
$('select').change(function(){

$(this).parent().append("<select>*insert options here *</select>");

});
```

However, based on your sample code, i suspect you more likely want something like the following.
Also, you need to make sure you're doing this after the DOM has loaded. So wrap it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#2').hide();
    $('#3').hide();
    $('#4').hide();

    $('#1').change(function(){

    $('#2').show();

    });


    $('#2').change(function(){

    $('#3').show();

    });

    $('#3').change(function(){

    $('#4').show();

    });

});
```

Comment: Can you please see my code and tell me where I'm going wrong?. I've added it into my question. Thanks

Comment: You cannot append something already defined in the document unless you were to copy it first. YOu need to move your definitions for the other select elements into the javascript and out of the html. It's probably not showing anything because your attempting to add elements with duplicate IDs.

Comment: BTW, you should lose the `display:none` styles too.